# structure of extension by quadratic elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Is it true that if $\sqrt{b}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a})$ for $a,b$ not squares in $\mathbb{Q}$, then $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b}))\cong Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}))$? Im seeing a bunch of examples where its holding (e.g. $a=-1,b=5$) and I was wondering if its a rule

Comment: Yes: it is always true. The Galois group in such extensions is always isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

As *abstract groups*, both Galois groups are isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$: explicitly, we have automorphisms
$$\sigma:\sqrt a\mapsto-\sqrt a, \sqrt b \mapsto \sqrt b\\\tau:\sqrt a\mapsto\sqrt a, \sqrt b \mapsto- \sqrt b$$
and one can check, using the fact that $\sqrt b\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt a)$, that $\sigma\tau = \tau\sigma,\ \sigma^2=\tau^2 = 1$.

However, bear in mind that this is an isomorphism of abstract groups, and  there is no canonical choice of isomorphism - i.e. any isomorphism requires us to manually and arbitrarily pick where each automorphism maps to.

In particular, these groups do not map to the same subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt a ,\sqrt b,\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)/\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: a question : how do I know that those are the only one automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$ ?

Comment: The extension has degree $4$ so there can be at most $4$ automorphisms.  So $1,\sigma,\tau,\sigma\tau$ must be all of them.

Comment: I guess I have to understand this : [wiki/Galois_theory#Second_example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Second_example)